# Laravel: Admins can see/edit/delete everything, but Authors can only their own

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My app has two roles: **admin** & **author** (by the way, there are tables: *roles*,  *permissions*, *permission_role*, *role_user*, there are Eloquent models *Role.php*, *Permission.php*... in model User.php there is a method called **hasRole** that checks whether the user has some role... and finally, in **AuthServiceProvider.php** there is:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles); 
        });
    }
}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

Anyway, I've created two roles: **admin** & **author**.

- Admins should be able to see/edit/delete all articles. Also, admins should be able to create and edit/delete all registered users.
- Author should be able to see/edit/delete only his own articles. Also, author should be able to edit only his own profile.

I'm not sure which is the best way to create this. Would it be a good idea to create the following permissions:

- manage_users
- edit_profile
- manage_articles
- edit_published_articles
- delete_published_articles

and then **admin** role would have all of these permissions, while **author** would have only: *edit_profile*, *edit_published_articles*, *delete_published_articles*...

Then, in **UsersController.php** in each method I would check the permissions:

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('edit_profile')) {
        if (Auth::user()->can('manage_users')) {
            $users = User::with('roles')->get();
            return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
        }
        $users = collect([Auth::user()]);
        return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
    return redirect('backend');
}

public function create(User $user)
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('manage_users')) {
        $roles = Role::lists('label', 'name');
        return view('backend.users.form', compact('user', 'roles'));
    }
    return redirect('backend');
}

public function store(Requests\StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('manage_users')) {
        $user = new User($request->only('name', 'email', 'password'));
        $user->save();

        $roleName = $request->input('role');
        $user->assignRole($roleName);

        session()->flash('status', 'User has been created.');
        return redirect(route('backend.users.index'));
    }
    return redirect('backend');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('edit_profile')) {

        if (Auth::user()->can('manage_users')) { 
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);
            $roles = Role::lists('label', 'name');
            foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
                $roleName = $role->name;
            }
            return view('backend.users.form', compact('user', 'roles', 'roleName'));
        }

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id) {  
            $roles = Role::lists('label', 'name');
            foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
                $roleName = $role->name;
            }
            return view('backend.users.form', compact('user', 'roles', 'roleName'));
        }
    }
    return redirect('backend');
}
// ... and so on...
```

BUT,  I'm quite sure that this is not the best way. Maybe I do not need to have the permissions at all - instead of checking permissions in controller methods it would be better to ask whether the user has a specific role (`if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))`), for example instead of:

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('edit_profile')) {
        if (Auth::user()->can('manage_users')) {
            $users = User::with('roles')->get();
            return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
        }
        $users = collect([Auth::user()]);
        return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
    return redirect('backend');
}
```

we would say:

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            $users = User::with('roles')->get();
            return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
        }
        $users = collect([Auth::user()]);
        return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

... or maybe this isn't the good way too? How would you do? Is it enough just to check in controller methods, or maybe there should be some Middleware  involved?

---

Since this is a long post, to summarize:

I've created two roles: **admin** & **author** and:

- Admins should be able to see/edit/delete all articles. Also, admins should be able to create and edit/delete all registered users.
- Author should be able to see/edit/delete only his own articles. Also, author should be able to edit only his own profile.

How would you do this?

Comment: Have a look at Laravel Authorization. (https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization). This is a much cleaner way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've got some more roles on my app but in basics I made it like this.

In my app, admin could do everything that moderators and more so in the model User I created functions like:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role == self::ROLE_ADMIN;
}

public function isModerator()
{
    return $this->role == self::ROLE_MODERATOR || $this->role == self::ROLE_ADMIN;
}
```

so basicly if you are admin you also are moderator. But you can make some other functions based on your roles/permissions and staff

and then I use the middlewares as this seems to be the best way to make it.

So the code could look like this:

```
//app/http/middleware/Admin.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class Admin
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {   
        if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } elseif (Auth::user()->isModerator()) {
                return redirect()->guest('moderate');
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

//app/http/middleware/Moderate.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class Moderate
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (!Auth::user()->isModerator()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

initialize it in kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    'moderate' => \App\Http\Middleware\Moderate::class,
    //...
];
```

and then in your controllers you can use:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('admin'); //or moderate or whatever
}
```